# how do you pronounce a rolling "o" as in "so" or "no"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, accent

I noticed that in New Zealand most people pronounce "o" at the end of "no" or "so" in a rather rolled manner - something closer to [our] instead of simple [ou]. For example, [lady in this video does this at 0:07](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ab_MLnr1Q4I&feature=youtu.be&t=7) . How do you make this sound?

For natives this might be a natural manner of pronoucing it, but I'm Russian and never heard it before :p

Comment: Sounds like a "non-rhotic" accent, where the "r" sound is dropped in some places and added in others.  It's not "normal" English, in most of the US.

Comment: That particular instance is just a slightly extended diphthong because the word is emphasised and followed by a comma. She uses the word *so* a bit later on too, where it's pronounced with the same sound but shorter because of the context.

Comment: There’s a change of pitch, on the second o. A drop.